# How to split a generator output in N elements batches?

Tags: python

I have a generator, what is the most pythonic way to get its output placed in lists of N elements?

For instance, in the code:

```
>>> the_splitter(xrange(11).__iter__(), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

i want the definition of `the_splitter()` function.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239591/python-is-there-a-library-function-for-chunking-an-input-stream).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356329/creating-a-python-dictionary-from-a-line-of-text/4356415#4356415) to related question.